# okhttp client throwing exception under TMG proxy server

Tags: java, https, proxy, okhttp

I'm using github's square OKHTTP client library for my java application as follows :

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.InetSocketAddress;
import java.net.Proxy;
import java.security.cert.CertificateException;
import java.security.cert.X509Certificate;

import javax.net.ssl.HostnameVerifier;
import javax.net.ssl.SSLContext;
import javax.net.ssl.SSLSession;
import javax.net.ssl.TrustManager;
import javax.net.ssl.X509TrustManager;


import com.squareup.okhttp.Authenticator;
import com.squareup.okhttp.Credentials;
import com.squareup.okhttp.OkHttpClient;
import com.squareup.okhttp.Request;
import com.squareup.okhttp.Response;


public class TestOkHttp {

static public void main(String argcp[]){
    try {
        OkHttpClient okHttpClient = new OkHttpClient();
          TrustManager[] trustAllCerts = new TrustManager[] {
                   new X509TrustManager() {

                    @Override
                    public X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        return null;
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void checkServerTrusted(X509Certificate[] arg0, String arg1)
                            throws CertificateException {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void checkClientTrusted(X509Certificate[] arg0, String arg1)
                            throws CertificateException {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                    }
                }};

                SSLContext sc = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
                sc.init(null, trustAllCerts, new java.security.SecureRandom());
                okHttpClient.setSslSocketFactory(sc.getSocketFactory());
            Proxy p=new Proxy(Proxy.Type.HTTP,new InetSocketAddress("10.1.1.0", 8080));
          okHttpClient.setProxy(p);
            HostnameVerifier hostNameVerifier = new HostnameVerifier() {

                @Override
                public boolean verify(String sourceHost, SSLSession arg1) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    return sourceHost.equals("serverwithtls.com");
                }

            };

            okHttpClient.setHostnameVerifier(hostNameVerifier);
        okHttpClient.setAuthenticator(new Authenticator() {

            @Override
            public Request authenticateProxy(Proxy proxy, Response response)
                    throws IOException {
                 String credential = Credentials.basic("username","password");
                            return response.request().newBuilder()
                                .header("Authorization", credential)
                                .build();               
                            }

            @Override
            public Request authenticate(Proxy arg0, Response arg1)
                    throws IOException {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                return null;
            }


        });
         Request request = new Request.Builder()
            .url("https://serverwithtls.com")
            .build();

        Response response = okHttpClient.newCall(request).execute();
        System.out.println(response.body().string());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
}
```

My network connection is behind a Microsoft TMG proxy server **which requires proxy user authentication**, I get the following exception upon execution of the above code :

java.net.ProtocolException: Unexpected status line: <HTML><HEAD><TITLE>Error Message</TITLE>
        at com.squareup.okhttp.internal.http.StatusLine.parse(StatusLine.java:54)
        at com.squareup.okhttp.internal.http.HttpConnection.readResponse(HttpConnection.java:187)
        at com.squareup.okhttp.Connection.makeTunnel(Connection.java:395)
        at com.squareup.okhttp.Connection.upgradeToTls(Connection.java:223)
        at com.squareup.okhttp.Connection.connect(Connection.java:153)
        at com.squareup.okhttp.Connection.connectAndSetOwner(Connection.java:169)
        at com.squareup.okhttp.OkHttpClient$1.connectAndSetOwner(OkHttpClient.java:119)
        at com.squareup.okhttp.internal.http.RouteSelector.next(RouteSelector.java:134)
        at com.squareup.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:314)
        at com.squareup.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:237)
        at com.squareup.okhttp.Call.getResponse(Call.java:233)
        at com.squareup.okhttp.Call.execute(Call.java:84)

I tried working under different proxy servers, worked perfectly.

Any help ?

Comment: any news on this problem? solution?

Comment: Been a while since I've worked on this, @MarianPaździoch OKhttp doesn't support TMG proxy (or at least back then), so I went with ApacheClient instead which successfully passed the TMG proxy server.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a bug in OkHttp, where were we're not throwing away the full response body on a 407. Open an issue on our GitHub issue tracker & I'll take a look. If the proxy of interest is reachable by the public Internet, send it to me privately, `jesse@swank.ca` and I'll confirm this.

Comment: I just posted it on OkHttp's issue tracker as you mentioned. However unfortunately our proxy of interest is not reachable. Is there another way I could contribute further to solving this issue?

Comment: If it isn't public, it would still be quite handy if you could share the proxy address with me privately. I'm jesse at swank.ca. Otherwise if you could capture the proxy's response with Wireshark, that'll be useful.