# Using retrofit behind a proxy

Tags: java, rest, retrofit

I am trying to call a Restful service with Retrofit from behind a proxy.
Is there anyway to to set proxy settings on Retrofit in the code?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26970670/okhttp-client-throwing-exception-under-tmg-proxy-server

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Retrofit does not have options for setting any network related settings. You need to set proxy to your Retrofit http client.

Set [Proxy](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/Proxy.html?is-external=true), to your `OkHttpClient` using `setProxy(proxy)` [method](https://square.github.io/okhttp/2.x/okhttp/com/squareup/okhttp/OkHttpClient.html#setProxy-java.net.Proxy-)

Answer (score 41):

Transforming Nikola's words into code:

```
java.net.Proxy proxy = new Proxy(Proxy.Type.HTTP,  new InetSocketAddress(proxyHost, proxyPort));
OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder().proxy(proxy).build();

Retrofit.Builder builder = new Retrofit.Builder().client(client);
Retrofit retrofit = builder.build();
```